tested api in third party worked but not my project
function filterCategory() {
    const selectedCategories = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.filter-button:checked')).map(checkbox => checkbox.id);
    showfilterProduct(selectedCategories);
}

function showfilterProduct(selectedCategories) {
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/products/filter", {
    category: [selectedCategories]
}, {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "*/*",
    }
})
.then(response => {
    const filterProduct = response.data;
    console.log(filterProduct);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log('error', error);
});

}
the problem is that when i tested in postman with body raw JSON it worked but when i tested in javascript its return back 403 and the backend responded
[Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "fptAptech.theSun.dto.FilterDto.getCategory()" because "criteria" is null]

its mean that in javascript some how doesn't read the category in the body of the javascript

If I am reading correctly, your backend is expecting a field called criteria in the request, while your Javascript is sending a category in the request, unless criteria is an object with a category field? I admit I don't know exactly how your code works but that's likely the problem

its just a Variable name for a class called FilterDto
class FilterDto implements Serializable {
private List category;
private List brand;
private List color;
private List gender;
private Double discount;
private Double price1;
private Double price2;
private Double price3;
private Double price4;
private String sortDirection;
private String sortFeatured;
private String sortNewest;
}

i don't know why responded back null

You should edit your post with the endpoint code in the backend too, or relevant docs if you're using a public API @C3ddyyy

Post the sample of your Postman request, you probably don't send the same output with your javascript code. Or Post the curl request.

If I am reading correctly, your backend is expecting a field called criteria in the request body, however, I am not sure you're binding it correctly.
If you're using Spring Boot, you should annotate the method parameter with @RequestBodyParam, make sure the object in question has setters and that setters have names that match the set(jsonKey) for every json key you're sending from the front-end. This should allow Spring-boot to do the rest of the work and bind your json request body to a Java POJO
